# Virtual DNS server for wifi clients

Tags: wireless-networking, dns

Is there a way to define some kind of virtual DNS server for users connected to my wifi network? I mean, in my network there is a web server connected directly to the router with an IP like 192.168.1.120, of course if somebody on the network writes that IP they will access the server with no problem, but i want them to write something more friendly like `http://localserver/` without having to modify the host file.

One solution could be to define the web server ip as DMZ (or redirect just the port 80) and use a DNS server like noip or dyndns pointing to the router ip, this will do the trick but this solution will require the router to be connected to internet, and I cant do that (design requirements).

Comment: Are the wireless clients using DHCP? It may be possible to force them to use your DNS servers, or possibly if your router already acts as one, just add the hostname to the router. This depends on make/model and firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a local DNS server. I use [Unbound](http://unbound.net/). it's a caching recursive DNS server but can also serve up local data. Use it to serve up your local data and for non-local data you may either forward the queries or use it as a resolver.